# iOS - Sending files over classical bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bonjour, mfi

We're developing a mobile app that will need to communicate over Bluetooth with one of our devices.
We can use BLE for the communication (propriety protocol) but at some point we also need to transfer a file from the iOS app to the device. The file is too big to be transferred over BLE and we will need to do so via classical Bluetooth.

The supported BT profiles don't support any kind of file transfer.

1. Some places mention that we can join the MFI program; would that
   mean that we will be able to have our own profile/protocol over
   classical BLE?
2. Any chance that Bonjour can help us?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you join the MFi program and have your hardware MFi certified then you could use the RFComm/SPP profile between your device and the iOS device.  Bonjour may also help you if you can get your device to implement a peer-to-peer IP network with the iOS device.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 when using the MFI device , except controlling it can we also get a file from it and send it one?

Comment: You can do whatever you program the device to do, but yes, you get access to the SPP legacy profile which is more suitable for file transfers.

Comment: @Paulw11 when you talk about RFComm/SPP you meant that the protocol needed to implement at the peripheral  device and i need to use library   like this for example?:
https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

Comment: Yes, your device would need to implement that Bluetooth profile. No, that library is for BLE. You would need to use the iOS external accessory framework, probably in Swift or Objective C. There may be PhoneGap support somewhere but since MFi information is available only to MFi members, probably not.

Comment: @Paulw11thanks for the info!